# Bullseye: E: Unable to locate package minecraft-pi

Tags: raspbian, minecraft, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Just got my Raspberry Pi 400 and tried the following to install Minecraft Pi Edition:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -y minecraft-pi
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package minecraft-pi
```

How do I resolve this? Minecraft Pi Edition is not preinstalled, and not available in Recommended Software. I'm using the latest Rapberry Pi OS based on Bullseye.

Comment: try **https://github.com/MCPI-Revival/minecraft-pi-reborn** or go to the minecraft web and type after the web name, edition/pi it didn't work for me but that might for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be out of luck, from the [changelog](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_full_armhf/release_notes.txt):

> - Python Games and Minecraft removed from Recommended Software - neither is compatible with bullseye

Someone else may have a workaround. For now, your simplest option is to downgrade to Buster.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in the standard packages, but you can go grab [Minecraft Pi Reborn](https://github.com/MCPI-Revival/minecraft-pi-reborn). This package was actually more difficult to install previously, but now that Raspbian is based on Bullseye, it's no problem.